# interactive shell commands through PHP

Tags: php, apache, shell

I have the following index.php file in /var/www folder.

```
<html>
<?php
$output = shell_exec("/home/ak/Documents/Translation/mosesdecoder/bin/moses -f /home/ak/Documents/Translation/ourOwnHinNorm/working/binarisedModel/moses.ini -input-file /home/ak/Documents/Translation/input.txt > /home/ak/Documents/Translation/output.txt");
//$output = shell_exec("cat /home/ak/Documents/Translation/instructions.txt");
echo $output;
?>
</html>
```

The code seeks to run `moses` program to read input from `input.txt` and write output to `output.txt`. I have run the above written `moses` command in my Ubuntu terminal and it works fine.

However, when I run the index.php through browser, the output.txt remains empty even after a long time.

NOTE: I have run `chmod -R 775 /home/ak/Documents/Translation/` and so I can access and execute files in that directory. As a test, I uncommented the commented line (second `shell_exec` in the `index.php`) which seeks to print the contents of `instructions.txt` placed in the same folder. Then, index.php was run through browser the contents of `instructions.txt` were printed on the browser.

Any idea, why the first `shell_exec` fails when run through browser?

Comment: try to run this from your terminal

sudo -u www-data /home/ak/Documents/Translation/mosesdecoder/bin/moses -f /home/ak/Documents/Translation/ourOwnHinNorm/working/binarisedModel/moses.ini -input-file /home/ak/Documents/Translation/input.txt > /home/ak/Documents/Translation/output.txt

then check output.txt. If it is empty - you must check www-data user's permissions.

Comment: the output.txt got filled on running the command you suggested...so I think there is no problem in permissions

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in **/home/ak/.bashrc**:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/ak/Documents/Translation/mosesdecoder/bin
```

Open a new terminal and type `moses` to test if it works.

Now, **replace**:

> $output = shell_exec("/home/ak/Documents/Translation/mosesdecoder/bin/moses -f /home/ak/Documents/Translation/ourOwnHinNorm/working/binarisedModel/moses.ini -input-file /home/ak/Documents/Translation/input.txt > /home/ak/Documents/Translation/output.txt");

with:

```
$output = shell_exec("moses -f /home/ak/Documents/Translation/ourOwnHinNorm/working/binarisedModel/moses.ini -input-file /home/ak/Documents/Translation/input.txt > /home/ak/Documents/Translation/output.txt");
```

Comment: it too didn't produce any output...and also I am providing the complete path to the executable in the shell command, so I don't think that just adding it to the environment path variables would make any difference....but thanks anyways